# Method from interface takes one parameter but it will be used with 2 different objects

Tags: c#, interface, arguments

I have to do a simple rpg game and there are 2 types of entities: heroes and monsters. Attack method will be implemented in both classes and it is contained by a interface called IAttack. The problem is that this method take a Monster type as parameter for hero class and a Hero type as parameter for monster class.

The code looks something like this:

The interface:

```
interface IAttack
{
     void Attack(Object oponnnent);
}
```

The Hero class(which implements IAttack):

```
public void Attack(Monster opponent)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

The Monster class(which implements IAttack):

```
public void Attack(Hero opponent)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

The problem is I can not pass different types of arguments.

Comment: Can you give more information about why you want to have the interface at all? Given the restrictions you've stated, I'm not sure how useful it'll really prove. Won't you always have a `Hero` when you want to attack a `Monster`, and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an `abstract` class that Monster and Hero dervice from.

```
public abstract class PlayerType
{
    public abstract int Health();
}
```

Then in your interface use the new abstract type:

```
interface IAttack
{
   void Attack(PlayerType oponnnent);
}
```

**Monster class:**

```
public class Monster : PlayerType, IAttack
{
    public override int Health()
    {
        return 100;
    }

    public void Attack(PlayerType hero)
    {

    }
}
```

**Hero class:**

```
public class Hero : PlayerType, IAttack
{
    public override int Health()
    {
       return 500; // He is a hero afterall ;)
    }

    public void Attack(PlayerType monster)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That`s kinda what I did but i want to pass a Hero type as parameter for Monster class and vice-versa.

Comment: @Gusti - In that case the interface it useless, remove it and pass the concrete type, Monster to the Hero class and Hero to the monster class as an argument to the method.

Comment: Isn`t there any other viable option to group somewhere the Attack method?

Comment: @Gusti - you could look at attempting to form some other type of composition, however I think it keep the solution simple the approach I've outlined is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two interfaces? Something that can attack and something that can be attacked?

```
public interface IAttackable
{
    void OnAttacked(IAttacker attacker);
}

public interface IAttacker
{
    void OnAttack(IAttackable opponet);
}

public class Hero : IAttacker, IAttackable
{
    public void OnAttack(IAttackable opponet)
    {
    }

    public void OnAttacked(IAttacker attacker)
    {
    }
}

public class Monster : IAttacker, IAttackable
{
    public void OnAttack(IAttackable opponet)
    {
    }

    public void OnAttacked(IAttacker attacker)
    {
    }
}
```